# How to stop Beamer \only overlay regenerating random parameters on parts of frame previously rendered

Tags: beamer, overlays, random-numbers, random, only

I have some lcg randomisation in a frame that uses `\only`. My problem is that the multiple PDF pages that are supposed to make the parts of the frame look like they are slowly appearing next to what has been rendered previously have different values of the randomisation, meaning that the illusion of revealing more of the frame is lost.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand} \only<2>{Text}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unless you're very unlucky and coincidentally get the same number twice, with pdflatex you'll see something like this: a PDF with two pages, on the first it says "439,384" and on the second it says "27,692 Text". What I want is for it to say e.g. "439,384" on the first and "439,384 Text" on the second.

Without `\only`, I can reset the lcg randomisation seed to generate the same random numbers. For example, this code produces the same pair of numbers twice:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand}
        \reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]
        \rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So I'm thinking that if I can get `\only` to run `\reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]` before it generates each new PDF page then that will sort it out. Or, better: to rewind the randomisation to before it started this frame, in the case where this isn't the first frame with random elements, but I don't know how to rewind the seed. At least with `\reinitrand` I can run this at the start of the frame so I know what the seed is at that point and then reset it to the same.

I tried `\begin{frame}\reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]`, `\reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]\begin{frame}`, `\reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]\only<2>{Text}` and `\only<2>{\reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=0] Text}`, but none of them produce the same number twice. I tried redefining `\only` using `\def\oldonly\only\renewcommand{\only}[2]{...}` but I couldn't get it to work and anyway I don't understand `\only` or conceptually what it is doing to know what I'm trying to change.

Note: I realise if there was just one `\rand` I could store the value of the generated number before the frame and use the stored version rather than generating it on frame - something like the below produces the same number on both PDF pages - but in the real case I use a command which uses `\rand` multiple times (at least twice) and the command is called several times on the page so this isn't practical.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\begin{document}
    \newcounter{myrand}
    \rand\setcounter{myrand}{\value{rand}}
    \begin{frame}
        \arabic{myrand} \only<2>{Text}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well I would create say ten random numbers before the frame and store them in sequence. Then you can select items inside a frame. Looks much easier then fighting against \only.

Comment: If you use pgfmath's RNG there is (probably) an API to remember the current seed and reinstall it for every slide.   Pgfmath is already included by beamer so nothing to lose.

Comment: I think, if I recall correctly, I'm using lcg for compatibility with XeTeX and LuaLaTeX. But thanks, it's a good thought!

Comment: Oh, and Ulrike's idea is a good workaround too, but in the real context I don't know how many random numbers I need in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I used @user187802's solution and put my code in a `\newsavebox` so the same thing was included each time it was included.

Just now, thinking about a problem elsewhere involving `lcg`, I just realised that I had forgotten how its seed initialisation parameters work. In fact, `seed` is supposed to be a number from 1 to 2^31-1. Putting `seed=0` means "the random number generator will be initialized with the time, the page number and the actual line of the file" (lcg manual), which is fine for the usual case but if I want to generate the same numbers twice all I needed to do is specify a `seed` in the correct range.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=123]\rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand} \only<2>{Text}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For greater randomness than specifying an actual seed number, it is possible to store a value derived as `lcg` does from "the time, the page number and the actual line of the file" and use this as the seed. That looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\begin{document}
    
    \newcounter{storedseed}
    \makeatletter
    \cr@nd =  \the\time
    \advance  \cr@nd \inputlineno
    \multiply \cr@nd \value{page}
    \advance  \cr@nd \the\year
    \multiply \cr@nd \the\month
    \multiply \cr@nd \the\day
    \advance  \cr@nd \inputlineno
    \setcounter{storedseed}{\cr@nd}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{frame}
        \reinitrand[first=0,last=1000,seed=\value{storedseed}]\rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand} \only<2>{Text}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a macro for the \setbox line

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[first=0,last=1000,seed=0]{lcg}
\newsavebox\RBox
\begin{document}
        
\sbox\RBox{\rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand}}
\begin{frame}
        \usebox\RBox\ \only<2>{Text}
\end{frame}

\sbox\RBox{\rand\arabic{rand},\rand\arabic{rand}}
\begin{frame}
        \usebox\RBox\ \only<2>{Text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay good. This means I can define a `\newsavebox` for each of the bits that need randomisation and just reuse those boxes, which is less faff than creating and storing a load of random variables. I had considered making each a `standalone` PDF and then using `\includegraphics` and this is much better, thanks.

Comment: `\sbox` must be _outside_ of the `frame` environment. That's all